# Cannot load nib/xib file in Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

We have a Mac application we wrote about 3 years ago. We've been maintaining it through all versions of OS X since Leopard (10.5). It's a 32 bit universal binary and is part of a suite of packages, all compiled and built the same way.

All apps are working under Mavericks except one, and only one part of it is broken. In this "broken" app we have a menu option that allows the user to open up a simple logging window. All this thing is is an NSPanel with a text view in it. When we open it, the spinning beach ball comes up and observing the console, it identifies this program as "hung."

This thing has been working for years. It works on both PPC and Intel from Leopard up through Mountain Lion. I thought for sure there was deprecated code in it somewhere, but I went through it and couldn't find any. There's really not much to it anyway. All it does is open up and spit out text. I then traced through the code and found out the nib wasn't loading.

I have Xcode 3.2.5 installed on this system (it's been upgraded since Snow Leopard) without iPhone support and it **seems** to work. In any case, I thought I'd take a look at the actual contents and window layout to see if maybe I had some unsupported or dated support, and when I double click on the xib file from Xcode, when Interface Builder opens up, it locks up too. We have I think 5 xib files in this application, so I double clicked on all of them and they all open up properly in Interface Builder. The only one locking up is this one. As a test, I opened the xib up in Xcode 4 and it opened up properly.

We can't really move to Xcode 4 because we have a fair number of clients (about 30%) still using Leopard and Snow  Leopard. We typically build in either Lion or Snow Leopard. but haven't had any problems compiling and building under Mountain Lion. This app, and all the other we have will compile and build using Xcode 3.2.5 on the Mavericks system. Everything seems to work **except** this one xib file.

Has anyone ever encountered something like this? Are we overlooking something? Are there changes to the OS we've overlooked? Is this an OS bug?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Retrospect backup, check whether the NIB files have been caught in a backup on the server.

I have recently found several applications which Retrospect cannot handle backing up the NIB files and does not let go of the NIB files until after the backup job has been stopped.